# Servlet not accessing google app engine api

Tags: android, google-app-engine, build.gradle, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

I imported a new servlet module into my project in Android Studio. When I try to use app engine api classes, the relevent code stays red and says cant resolve symbol. I can even import classes like Datastoreservice or anything. Please help me becusae this has been a huge pain in my ass. my gradle file should compile it since I have the statement in there. Here is my gradle file for my backend servlet.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.28'
    }
}

    repositories {
    jcenter();
}

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'appengine'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

    dependencies {
      appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.28'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-java-sdk
        compile group: 'com.google.appengine', name: 'appengine-java-sdk', version: '1.9.28'

        compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

    }

    appengine {
      downloadSdk = true
      appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, I didn't have compile 'com.google.cloud:gcloud-java-datastore:0.2.6' in my gradle. This was extremely hard to find. LOL I went through pages and pages of documentation until I found this.